# How to force Google interface language to english with GET params?

Tags: url, get

I want that Google uses only English as interface language, despite the IP I am currently using is from a non English speaking country.

I can do so manually with the settings in the Google language settings, but I couldn't identify a GET parameter that is responsible for the Google Language interface settings.

I want to make raw Get requests with a networking library. So I cannot set the settings in the google user interface.

The search reference wasn't particularly useful: http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 4):

Found it:

**Optional. The hl parameter specifies the interface language (host language) of your user interface. To improve the performance and the quality of your search results, you are strongly encouraged to set this parameter explicitly.**

from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#hl

Comment: Googling here once in a while to force language. For street names to appear in hebrew in google map :
?hl=iw